# How to use fscanf properly?

Tags: c, scanf

I have been at this piece of code for half a day now and I still can't get it to work.

```
while(fscanf(file, "%d {", &macroList[count]) == 1)
{
    count++;
}

for(count = 0; count < sizeof macroList/sizeof(macroList[0]); count++)
{
    printf("%d ", macroList[count]);
}
```

My file looks like this:

`1{ D }2{ D }3{ D }4{ D }5{ D }6{ D }7{ D }8{ D }9{ D }10{ D }11{ D }12{ D }13{ D }14{ D }15{ D }16{ D }17{ D }18{ D }19{ D }20{ D }21{ D }22{ D }23{ D }24{ D }`
My output is:

`1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

And I want it to be like this:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 23 24`

My questions are, why is fscanf only catching the "first entry" and how can I fix it? Also a version of this fscanf that would catch any white-space between the integer and left bracket would be appreciated. I have this

`while(fscanf(file, "%d %[^{]{", &macroList[count]) == 2)`

but the output is the same.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

I hope the formatting isn't too confusing, first time using this.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, although, the file exactly like that and it wasn't working for me, the real format of the file would be something like this
`1{ D,DL,L }2{ _D W52 ^DL. 123 }`. So just about anything of any amount can be inside the brackets.

Comment: Shouldn't your format string be `"%d { D }"`?

Comment: Your loop controls seem a bit odd; you increment `count` (is it from zero? — it isn't completely clear) and then reset it to zero.  That's going to give you grief too, but the format string is mishandling the constant text — the `{`, spaces, `D`, and `}` — as diagnosed in the earlier comments.

Comment: @caveman it does, thanks! However I failed to mention that between the brackets can be just about anything in it such as `1{ D,DL,L }2{ _D W52 ^DL. 123 }` in which case it would fail again.

Comment: Do you want the numbers inside the brackets?

Comment: @rpattiso No, everything inside the brackets would be ignored.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler count is defined just above the while loop and is initialized as 0, I'm just reusing the variable in the second loop.

Comment: I partially misread the question, but there are still problems.  You need to preserve the value of `count` so you don't read un-read values in the printing loop, and you also need to check that you don't try to read too many values into the `macroList` array.  You might use `enum { SIZE_MACROLIST = sizeof(macroList) / sizeof(macroList[0]) }; for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MACROLIST; i++) { if (fscanf(file, "%d { D }", &macroList[i]) != 1) break; }` for the first loop, and then `int count = i; for (i = 0; i < count; i++) printf("%d ", macroList[i]); putchar('\n');` for the second loop.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
fscanf(file, "%d {", &macroList [count])
```

To

```
fscanf(file, "%d {%*[^}]}", &macroList [count])
```

Here,`%d` scans an `int` and stores it in the address of `macroList[count]` and then the whitespace in the format string expects any number of whitespace characters(spaces, newlines etc) including none. Then, the `fscanf` scans a `{` and then it scans and discards everything until a `}` is found(`%[^}]`) and lastly, scans a `}`.

Your code did not work execept for the first iteration because `"%d {"`, expects an `int` first, then any number of whitespace characters including none and a opening bracket(`{`). This is ok for the first run but not for the rest of the iterations as the next thing to be scanned is `" D }"` and this dosen't match the format string `"%d {"`.

Note that the above method to extract data from a file will fail(except for the first iteration) if there is nothing between `{` and  `}`. So, use the following [as suggested by @chux](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28891368/how-to-use-fscanf-properly/28891602?noredirect=1#comment46045546_28891602) in the comments below:

```
fscanf(file, "%d {%*[^}]" ,&macroList [count]);
fscanf(file, "}");
```

Comment: "scans a { and then it scans and discards everything until a } is found" has a corner case problem: _something_ has to be between `{` and `}`.  Alternative: `fscanf(file, "%d {%*[^}]", &macroList [count]); fscanf(file, "}");`

Comment: @chux , Oh. I forgot about that! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `"%d {"`, you will read a `int`, then a whitespace and a opening backet. Thats why your first output is correct. After that, the same command will be used to keep reading the file, but now the string to be read is `" D }"`, that is, a whitespace, an uppercase 'D' and closing bracket, by no means what you actually wanted.

Use `"%d { D }"` inside your `fscanf` to fix your issue, for that is exactly the repeating pattern: it will read an `int`, a whitespace, an opening bracket, another whitespace, a 'D',a final whitespace and then a closing bracket. Also, keep in mind to use the `fopen` and `fclose` functions correctly.

Comment: A whitespace in the format string tells `fscanf` to scan **any number of whitespace including none**.